# postgresql invalid command \

Tags: postgresql, database, sql

When trying to import an .out file back into a postgres database, I get many (thousands) of rows like this: psql:G:/Backup/main_db_backup.out:251875: invalid command \

With a different number where "251875" is each line

Does this mean the restore will not work?

Has anyone encountered this before? I couldn't find anything online regarding this message during a restore

Thank you for any assitance!

Comment: How did you create the file?

Comment: This is **almost** certainly a `COPY` command that has some error in the middle causing the `COPY` to abort and treat the remaining lines as (invalid) SQL.  You'll need to capture the very first error message and start from there.

Comment: Run psql with `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1`

Comment: Sorry cannot comment yet...
These errors I get when I run `COPY` command against table with different structure than exported data.
Output file from `COPY` command is tab delimited and tries to fill target table columns just by plain order of values in file.